# Keycode disambiguation on Chrome on OSX

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos, google-chrome

I'd like to disable the '-' key on an input on keydown.

My first idea was using the usual solution:

```
if(e.keycode == 189 || e.which == 189 ){
  return false;
}
```

but in fact, the '-' and the ')' has the same keycode on mac (i.e. 189)
and I don't want my closing parenthesis key to be blocked as well.

since they have the same keycode, the fromCharCode method is irrelevant here (both awkwardly yielding '½')

is there an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use event.key instead of event.keyCode.

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
  if (event.defaultPrevented) {
    return; // Do nothing if the event was already processed
  }

  if (event.key == '-') {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}, true);
```

You can find out more about KeyboardEvents in javascript [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent). There is stated that `keyCode` and `which` are both deprecated.

---

I've added a more elaborate snippet which shows how to block a key only on a specific element.

```js
document.getElementById("field1").addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
  if (event.defaultPrevented) {
    return; // Do nothing if the event was already processed
  }

  if (event.key == '-') {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}, true);
```

```html
<input id="field1" type="text" />
<input id="field2" type="text" />
```